# Why is my numerical algorithm behaving differently on two different machines?

Tags: linux, windows, gfortran

I am programming a version of the BFGS algorithm for multidimensional optimization in Fortran 90.  I have written the code, compiled it with gfortran on my laptop (running Windows Vista), and it works fine.  But when I try to use the same code on a server running Linux 6, it gives incorrect results.  It is the exact same code and it compiles fine, the results it produces are just wrong.  Namely, it seems to be developing a floating point arithmetic error at some early phase of the algorithm and only produces one line of numerical results before it starts producing NaN's.  I can only assume it's something about the server environment, but how can I find out what it is and how can I correct my code accordingly?

Comment: Have you read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de)?

Comment: I am familiar with the basics of floating point arithmetic, and I think my code was designed decently well at least in so far as it runs and gives correct results for test minimization problems on my laptop.  My question is regarding code performing differently across different platforms.  I don't understand why my code is working on windows and not on linux.  It was compiled with gfortran on both platforms.

Comment: One common problem is compiling code with debugging information in one environment, then compiling code with no debugging information in another environment. If you have objects or arrays writing beyond their limits in the debug versions, it just writes over debug information and won't affect the code running.  You could compile both with debug information and see how that goes.

Comment: @clioi, different floating-point behaviour is definitely a possible source of problems between different platforms.

Comment: @CarlNorum, would you have any specific advice or reference that I could read about how to determine what such issues could possibly be?

Comment: @kermit, the code is relatively short, only ~300 lines, and I am pretty sure it was compiled in the exact same way with the exact same information in both locations.

Comment: How do you load in the input data that your algorithm operates upon? Hardcoded into the code or from files, some other way?

Comment: The program is designed to minimize a multivariable function.  In this particular implementation, the function is an actual Fortran function which, when passed a vector of appropriate length, evaluates the function at that point.

Comment: So in answer to your question, it's all hardcoded into the program, it's not passed in at runtime or read from files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem** is described here (CERT.org): **[FLP00-C. Understand the limitations of floating point numbers](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP00-C.+Understand+the+limitations+of+floating+point+numbers)**

> **The reason for this behavior is that Linux uses the internal extended precision mode of the x87 floating-point unit (FPU) on IA-32 machines for increased accuracy during computation.** When the result is stored into memory by the assignment to c, the FPU automatically rounds the result to fit into a double. The value read back from memory now compares unequally to the internal representation, which has extended precision. **Windows does not use the extended precision mode, so all computation is done with double precision, and there are no differences in precision between values stored in memory and those internal to the FPU.** For GCC, compiling at optimization level 1 or higher eliminates the unnecessary store into memory, so all computation happens within the FPU with extended precision

**The solution** is described here: **[FLP02-C. Avoid using floating point numbers when precise computation is needed](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP02-C.+Avoid+using+floating+point+numbers+when+precise+computation+is+needed)** with two examples, an incorrect example showing the problem, and a corrected example without the problem:

> "This code may be fixed by replacing the floating-point numbers with integers for the internal additions. Floats are used only when printing results and when doing the division to compute the mean."